# Count input errors and disable submit button Jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, input, submit

Well, I developed a simple field validation script registration, and wanted to make if there was some error, some blank, was disabled the button to send the form.

I have several fields, if one or all are empty the send button is disabled.

A part of my script:

```
$('#tipo_pessoa').focusout(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).toggleClass('inputs_error-select')
        $("label[for='tipo_pessoa']").fadeIn().html('<img src="../imagens/error.png" align="absmiddle" />&nbsp;Campo obrigatório');

        ErrorSound();
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass('inputs, inputs_error-select')
        $("label[for='tipo_pessoa']").text('');

    }
});


$('#razao_social').focusout(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '' || $(this).val() == $(this).attr("placeholder")) {
        $(this).removeClass('inputs').addClass('inputs_error');
        $("label[for='razao_social']").fadeIn().html('<img src="../imagens/error.png" align="absmiddle" />&nbsp;O Campo Razão Social deve ser preenchido');
        ErrorSound();
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('inputs_error').addClass('inputs');
        $("label[for='razao_social']").text('');

    }
});
```

I need a script to count / check for any error, if any one or more errors, the submit button is disabled

Comment: This is to much to try and get, but could'nt you just count the number of elements that have the class `inputs_error-select`, would that be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent form submission when there is empty field:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
   return $('#input1, #input2').filter(function() {
      return $.trim(this.value).length === 0;
   }).length === 0;
});
```

Comment: Cool, I will test this function, if someone has something more than post here